# Bool list check if every item in list is false

Tags: c#, list, boolean

I have a `List<bool>` with lots of values. What is the most efficient way to check if every single item in the list equals `false`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A significantly faster solution, not mentioned here, is using **[`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx)**

```
if (!myList.Contains(true))
    // Great success - all values false!
```

---

I have compared `Contains` against `IEnumerable.Any` and `Contains` returns faster. In my tests `IEnumerable.All` performed the same as `IEnumerable.Any`, perhaps a similar algorithm is used for both these functions under the hood. I also checked `IEnumerable.Exists` which performed better than `IEnumerable.Any` and `IEnumerable.All`, but was still slower than `Contains`.

Of a list of 10,000,000 bool entries *(I also tried 0 and 1 entries, with similar results)*, I came up with the following metrics:

> Elapsed via **Any** = **95ms**
>
> Elapsed via All = 88ms
>
> Elapsed via Exists = 27ms
>
> Elapsed via **Contains** = **17ms**
>
> ***Contains is ~5.59x faster** than Any!*

Tested with the following code:

```
// setup initial vars
var myList = new List<bool>();
for (int x = 0; x < 10000000; x++)
    myList.Add(false);  

var containsAllFalse = false;
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

// start test
sw.Start();
containsAllFalse = !myList.Any(x => x);
sw.Stop();

// get result for Any
var timeAny = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

// reset variable state (just in case it affects anything)
containsAllFalse = false;   

// start test 2
sw.Restart();
containsAllFalse = myList.All(x => x == false);
sw.Stop();

// get result for All
var timeAll = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

// reset variable state (just in case it affects anything)
containsAllFalse = false;   

// start test 3
sw.Restart();
containsAllFalse = !myList.Exists(x => x == true);
sw.Stop();

// get result for All
var timeExists = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

// reset variable state (just in case it affects anything)
containsAllFalse = false;   

// start test 4
sw.Restart();   
containsAllFalse = !myList.Contains(true);          
sw.Stop();

// get result from Contains
var timeContains = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

// print results
var percentFaster = Math.Round((double)timeAny / timeContains, 2);
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed via Any = {0}ms", timeAny);
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed via All = {0}ms", timeAll);
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed via Exists = {0}ms", timeExists);
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed via Contains = {0}ms", timeContains);
Console.WriteLine("Contains is ~{0}x faster than Any!", percentFaster);
```

---

---

*Note this will only work with types where type can only have two states (i.e. it won't work variables of >2 states, such as `Nullable<bool>`)*

Comment: Nice performance comparison. Where there are many solutions performance takes priority.

Comment: Is there a way to perform this if the list isnt a bool but of a class that contains a boolean value ?

Comment: "..as it can return early at the first occurrence of true.." so can (and do) both `All` and `Any`. While `Contains` may be faster, *it is not faster due to early termination*. Check the implementation of in the [.NET Reference Source's IEnumerable.All](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,1305) which, as I would expect, is lazy and does not force evaluation of the entire sequence.

Comment: @user2864740 great point - thank you! I'll edit the OP to reflect this.

Answer (score 48):

You can use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it will find satisfy the condition on first match. As Habib rightly said better to use Any as Enumerable.All would return true for an Empty list of bool.

```
!lst.Any(c=> c == true);
```

OR use [Enumerable.All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
lst.All(c=> c == false);
```

Comment: +1, Better to use `Any`, since `Enumerable.All` would return `true` for an Empty list of bool.

Comment: +1 This performs better than All(), because it does always iterates the whole list; it stops when it find one

Comment: @AdrianCarneiro Uhm ..? That is not making sense to me. Both are lazy and require looking at the same number of elements in this case.

Comment: Shouldn't they have the *same* result if used correctly. One should be negated. `!Any(f(x))` ~ `All(!f(x))`. That is, "If there are *no* false values?" as opposed to "If every value is not true?"

Comment: @user2864740, negated is just a short way of providing `Any` with the bool value, Consider the following code: `List<bool> list = new List<bool>(); var b1 = list.All(r => r == false); var b2 = list.Any(r => r == false);` , now `b1` would be `true` and `b2` would be false. It is just that `Enumerable.All` behaves differently on an empty list.

Comment: @Habib On any empty list, l, l.All => true, l.Any => false, so `l.Any != l.All` as above.

Comment: @user2864740, yes just for an **Empty List** :)

Comment: obviously the list contains some items.and these two statement are not the same.First return `true` if there is any item that equals to `true` Second return true if all item's equals to `false`.You need a negation operator on first statement.

Comment: @Selman22, yes, I pasted the wrong code, `List<bool> list = new List<bool>();var tttt = list.All(r => r == false);var b2 = list.Any(r => r == true);` the first comparison should have been with `false`. In the above `b1` would be true, since the list is empty, Although its a defined behaviour , but could be misleading.

Comment: @Habib sorry I meant the original answer but you right too :)

Comment: @Habib "It is just that Enumerable.All behaves differently on an empty list" is *misleading* in relationship to the answer. As I've explained, `!Any(f(x)) ~ All(!f(x))` (that is, the *negation* of the result over a *negated* predicate is required for equivalency) so if the results don't align then the function is being used incorrectly, as was the initial non-negated usage of Any presented in this answer. I know of no reason to prefer Any over All in LINQ To Objects, except for intent readability and preference. When used correctly (see above) the two forms are *semantically equivalent*.

Answer (score 18):

I agree with the use of [IEnumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)/[All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However, I disagree with the currently most-voted answer (which was wrong at the time of writing this) and several of the associated comments of Any vs All.

These following operations are *equivalent* semantically. Note that the negations are applied *both* inside, on the predicate, and on the result of the operation.

```
!l.Any(x => f(x))
l.All(x => !f(x))
```

Now, in this case we are thus looking for:

> If it is *not* the case that there is *any* true value.

```
!l.Any(x => x)  // f(x) = x == true
```

*Or*,

> It is the case that *every* value is *not* true.

```
l.All(x => !x)  // f'(x) = !f(x) = !(x == true)
```

There is nothing special for empty lists the result is the same: e.g. `!empty.Any(..)` is false, as is `empty.All(..)` and the above equivalence relation remains valid.

In addition, *both* forms are lazily evaluated and require the same number of evaluations in [LINQ To Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx); internally the difference, for a sequence implementation, is merely negating the check on the predicate and the result value.

Comment: Is there a way to perform this if the list isnt a bool but of a class that contains a boolean value ?

Comment: @RyanN1220 Yes. LINQ's IEnumerable is flexible in this aspect as a function is accepted in many contexts (there are restrictions for certain providers such a LINQ-to-EF, eg.). The `All/Any` functions take an optional `Func<T, bool>`. In the above, `f(x)` is a "some code" (and/or a function) that accepts x and return a bool. Eg., given `var a = new [] { Tuple.Create(1, true), Tuple.Create(1, false) }`, then `a.Any(x => x.Item2)` is true and `a.All(x => x.Item2)` is false.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `LINQ's` `All` method:

```
list.All(x => x == false);
```

This will return `false` immediately if it finds a value that equals to `true`.

Comment: Is there a way to perform this if the list isnt a bool but of a class that contains a boolean value ?

Comment: @RyanN1220 the lambda variable "x" represents the object here. so all you need is to change the condition `x.SomeBoolProperty == false` or `!x.SomeBoolProperty`