# Detect if any object with tag is inside of trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an empty object with box collider (trigger), inside this empty object I have some cubes that have the same tag, so I want to instantiate a Text when all of those cubes becomes outside of the empty object (using OnTriggerExit).

This is the code I tried but it didn't work:

```
List<string> contacts = new List<string>();

void OnCollisionExit(Collision col)
{
    contacts.Add(col.gameObject.tag);
    if (contacts.Contains("Cube"))
    {
        GameObject canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
        Text text = Instantiate(Text, new Vector3(562, 1800, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        text.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you have problem with when implementing it? Maybe you are looking for `Enumerable.All` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618284/bool-list-check-if-every-item-in-list-is-false)?

Comment: is there only one "another object" here? Are there only certain tags that you want to check this on or is this for any collision?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect if a gameObject has collided with two other specific objects at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923585/how-can-i-detect-if-a-gameobject-has-collided-with-two-other-specific-objects-at)

Comment: @Ruzihm I will explain more: So I have an empty object with box collider (trigger), inside this empty object I have some cubes that have the same tag, so I want to call a function when all of those cubes becomes outside of the empty object (using OnTriggerExit).

Comment: @Ruzihm Can you please check the post, I've added the code I tried

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Can you please check the post, I've added the code I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of how many cubes are in the trigger. Set it at the scene start, increment using OnTriggerEnter and decrement using OnTriggerExit when the tag is "Cube". As soon as it hits zero, call your function.

```
// Inside of MonoBehavior on the GameObject with the trigger.
public int cubesCurrentlyInTrigger;

void Start() 
{
    cubesCurrentlyInTrigger = 3; // Or however many cubes at start
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) 
{
    // check for entering cubes
    if (col.tag == "Cube")
    {
        cubesCurrentlyInTrigger++;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider col) 
{
    // check for exiting cubes
    if (col.tag == "Cube") 
    {
        cubesCurrentlyInTrigger--; // Could use `--cubesInTrigger` inside the if,
                                   // but this is more readable

        if (cubesCurrentlyInTrigger == 0) 
        {
            DoFunction(); // Put your function here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was so helpful, Thank you!